# Android MediaPlayer create failed

Tags: java, android, media-player, ioexception

My problem is the following:
I want to create a really simple App, that shall play a song when i press a button.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

int counter; 
Button add1;
Button sub1;
Button sound;
TextView display;
MediaPlayer mySound;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_main);
        if (mySound==null){
            mySound = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.tetris_theme);
        }
        else { mySound.release();
        }

    sound = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    display = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);

    sound.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (mySound==null){
                display.setText("Error");
            }
            else {
                mySound.start();
            }
        }

    });

}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }
}


}
```

When I run the app and press the button "sound" it displays "Error"(since I checked whether `mySound` is null or not)

So, I figured that meant that the `mySound` MediaPLayer I created is null.
I checked the logcat and it showed the following:

```
11-25 14:27:02.900: E/MediaPlayer(1026): error (1, -2147483648)
11-25 14:27:02.920: D/MediaPlayer(1026): create failed:
11-25 14:27:02.920: D/MediaPlayer(1026): java.io.IOException: Prepare failed.: status=0x1
11-25 14:27:02.920: D/MediaPlayer(1026):    at android.media.MediaPlayer.prepare(Native Method)
11-25 14:27:02.920: D/MediaPlayer(1026):    at         android.media.MediaPlayer.create(MediaPlayer.java:850)
11-25 14:27:02.920: D/MediaPlayer(1026):    at     com.example.simpleapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:49)
11-25 14:27:02.920: D/MediaPlayer(1026):    at     android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5242)
11-25 14:27:02.920: D/MediaPlayer(1026):    at     android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
11-25 14:27:02.920: D/MediaPlayer(1026):    at     android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2161)
11-25 14:27:02.920: D/MediaPlayer(1026):    at     android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2258)
11-25 14:27:02.920: D/MediaPlayer(1026):    at     android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:138)
11-25 14:27:02.920: D/MediaPlayer(1026):    at     android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1209)
11-25 14:27:02.920: D/MediaPlayer(1026):    at     android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
11-25 14:27:02.920: D/MediaPlayer(1026):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
11-25 14:27:02.920: D/MediaPlayer(1026):    at     android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5026)
11-25 14:27:02.920: D/MediaPlayer(1026):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-25 14:27:02.920: D/MediaPlayer(1026):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
11-25 14:27:02.920: D/MediaPlayer(1026):    at     com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
11-25 14:27:02.920: D/MediaPlayer(1026):    at      com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:602)
 11-25 14:27:02.920: D/MediaPlayer(1026):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I guess that means that create failed, because prepare failed, but why?
I already searched for that problem on this website and found a hundred different cases but none 
of the solutions did work for me.

the file I want to play is in mp3 and is located in my R.raw folder.
I can play it on my PC without any problems, so I guess it can't be corrupt or something.

I already tried with different types like .ogg and .aac but nothing(!!) works.

Answer (score 2):

This will occur Your MediaPlayer object is not having any resource associated with it and so returned null.

Your file is having special characters. remove special characters and it must be in lower case.

```
mySound= MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.tetristheme);
```

your media file shoouldf be in the name `tetristheme`

Now you can use `mySound.start()` to start playing your media

Comment: hm tried that but it didn`t work... same errors. I just can't figure out why. Thanks for the suggestion anyway

Comment: How do you catch this error? I want to check if the mediaPlayer == null due to a faulty uri, then do stuff.